# react parallax in gatsby issue

Tags: html, css, gatsby, react-parallax

I have a vanilla html and css sample project that works fine with a parallax effect using three images and a text container.

> html

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
      <header>
        <img
          src="imgs/bg.jpg"
          class="background"
        />
        <img
          src="imgs/forest_transparent.png"
          class="foreground"
        />
        <img
          src="imgs/rock-mountaineern-right.png"
          class="foreground"
        />
        <div class="header__text-box">
          <h1 class="heading-primary">SCRUM-HR</h1>
          <p class="heading-primary--sub">
            SCRUM HR ÄR EN BYRÅ SOM ÄR LÅNGT IFRÅN LAGOM DÄR VÅR STRÄVAN ÄR DIN
            TRYGGHET.
          </p>
          <p class="heading-primary--sub">
            VI LYSSNAR IN DINA BEHOV OCH HJÄLPER DIG ATT NÅ FRAMGÅNG.
          </p>
        </div>
      </header>

      <section>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse facilis
        unde illo neque at hic quisquam, nulla consectetur, itaque maxime sit
        iusto aliquam culpa reiciendis eaque recusandae vitae modi, animi
        expedita perferendis inventore. Culpa incidunt odit dicta quibusdam
        ullam facilis eum magnam, consectetur voluptates praesentium, pariatur
        eos nihil! 
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
```

> css

```
header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
  
}

.background {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
  
  
}

.foreground {
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.1), rgba(40, 112, 200, 0.8))
}

.background,
.foreground {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}



.page {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.header__text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center; 
color: white;}

  .heading-primary--main {
    display: block;
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 3.5rem;
    animation-name: moveInLeft;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    text-shadow: 
  0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 
  0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
  2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    /*
        animation-delay: 3s;
        animation-iteration-count: 3;
        */ }

.heading-primary--sub {
          display: block;
          font-size: 1.55rem;
          font-weight: 700;
          /* letter-spacing: 1.75rem; */
          animation: moveInRight 1s ease-out; }
```

But when trying to emulate this in a gatsby page; I am not able to align the image properly, the bg.jpg has to be in the background, then in front of it, the forest_transparent.png, then in front it the, rock-mountaineern-right.png and the text in the front of everything.

> gatsby

```
// TestComponent.js

import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Parallax } from 'react-parallax'
import bgImage from '../../images/bg.jpg'
import forestImage from '../../images/forest_transparent.png'
import rockImage from '../../images/rock-mountaineern-right.png'

const ParallaxContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;
`

const BackgroundImage = styled(Parallax)`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -3; /* Move it to the back */
`

const ForegroundImage1 = styled(Parallax)`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -2; /* Move it behind the text */
`

const ForegroundImage2 = styled(Parallax)`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1; /* Move it behind the text */
`

const TextContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
`

const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 7rem;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
    2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
`

const SubTitle = styled.p`
  font-size: 1.5rem;
`

const TestComponent = () => {
  return (
    <ParallaxContainer>
      <BackgroundImage
        bgImage={bgImage}
        strength={300}
      ></BackgroundImage>
      <ForegroundImage1
        bgImage={forestImage}
        strength={250}
      ></ForegroundImage1>
      <ForegroundImage2
        bgImage={rockImage}
        strength={200}
      ></ForegroundImage2>
      <TextContainer>
        <Title>SCRUM-HR</Title>
        <SubTitle>
          SCRUM HR ÄR EN BYRÅ SOM ÄR LÅNGT IFRÅN LAGOM DÄR VÅR STRÄVAN ÄR DIN
          TRYGGHET.
        </SubTitle>
        <SubTitle>
          VI LYSSNAR IN DINA BEHOV OCH HJÄLPER DIG ATT NÅ FRAMGÅNG.
        </SubTitle>
      </TextContainer>
    </ParallaxContainer>
  )
}

export default TestComponent
```

but my images are not aligned as I described, but beneath each other. What have I done wrong?